# Construction of an exact sequence $1 \to N_{16} \to G_{64} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, exact-sequence

Let us consider the following possible exact sequence $$1 \to N_{16} \to G_{64} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times  \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to 1$$

$\bullet$ The full group is a non-Abelian finite group $G_{64}$ with 64 group elements.

$\bullet$ The normal subgroup is a non-Abelian finite group $N_{16}$ with 16 group elements.

$\bullet$ The quotient group is a Abelian finite group $Q=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times  \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with 4 group elements.

> The rule of the games (a puzzle told by my friend):

We want to impose the following conditions:

$\bullet$ $G_{64}$ contains generators $i$, $X$ and $Y$, such that
$$XY=iYX$$
with $i \cdot i=-1$.

$\bullet$ $N_{16}$ contains generators $X$ and $Y^2$. 
  But we find that $XY^2=-Y^2X$.

$\bullet$ The quotient group is $Q=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times  \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

> Questions: What are the names of groups $N_{16}$ and $G_{64}$? Are they product of cyclic groups with Dihedral groups?

```
My guess is the following 

(which may not be correct, as my attempt to solve my friend's puzzle):
```

$\bullet$  So we imagine that the $G_{64}$ is fully generated by $i,X$ and $Y$. Here $i^4=1$. (And we may need to check that  $X^4=Y^4=1$ is true(?) or not.)

$\bullet$  so $N_{16}$ can be fully generated $-1$, $X$ and $Y^2$ (?).

$\bullet$ $Q$ is generated by $i$ and $Y$ (?). The $i$ and $Y$ generators are of order 2 in $Q$, but they are of order 4 in $G$.

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to read. What is the difference between "generated" and "fully generated"? What is -1 exactly? Just a central involution? You are missing the word "by" after every "generated". etc.

Comment: Since $N_{16}$ is normal and contains $X$,  it should contain $X^{Y^{-1}}=i^{-1}X$ and thus also $i$. I think this contradicts what you want (although I'm not sure, because of your terminology).

Comment: For example, I think the above shows that $N_{16}$ in fact has order at least $32$....

Comment: Hi verret, I separate my guess, and the given puzzle. Some of the statements are guessed by me. While you should follow the rule of the game if the rules give the consistent solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question may be hard to digest in disguise, but it makes perfect sense. And I have an answer for it,

The full group $G_{64}$ contains group elements $X$, $Y$, $i$ with
$$X=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&1\\ 1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ \end{pmatrix}$$
$$Y=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\ 0&i&0&0\\ 0&0&-1&0\\ 0&0&0&-i\\ \end{pmatrix}$$
where my proposal satisfies your:
$$XY=iYX$$
so
$$G_{64}=\langle i^{n_1} X^{n_2} Y^{n_3}|XY=iYX,n_1\in \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z},n_2\in \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z},n_3\in \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\rangle$$
with $i^2=-1$, $X^4=Y^4=i^4=1$, the 4-by-4 identity element.

The normal subgroup $N_{16}$ contains group elements $X$, $Y^2$, $-1$ with
$$X=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&1\\ 1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ \end{pmatrix}$$
$$Y^2=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\ 0&-1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&-1\\ \end{pmatrix}$$
with what you desired,
$$XY^2=-Y^2X,$$
so
$$N_{16}=\langle (-1)^{m_1} X^{m_2} Y^{2m_3}|XY^2=-Y^2X, m_1\in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},m_2\in \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z},m_3\in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\rangle$$
with $i^2=-1$.

Last, we can consider the quotient group is isomorphic to 
$$Q \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},$$
in the full group $G_{64}$ the two generators of $Q$ is indeed $i$ and $Y$. They are order 4 in $G_{64}$ ($i^4=Y^4=1$), but they are order 2 in $Q$.

Everything satisfies what you imposed. And your guess is basically right. I don't have the name of the group though. Not sure how $G_{64}$ and $N_{16}$ are named.

Comment: Thanks, your answer seems correct! Let me know if your know what are the names of the groups (if there are such terms).

Comment: This is wrong for reasons I already explained. If $G$ is generated by $X$, $Y$ and $i$, then it is generated by $X$ and $Y$ (since $XY=iYX$). If $N$ is generated by $X$, $Y^2$ and $-1$, then it is generated by $X$ and $Y^2$ (since $XY^2=(-1)Y^2X$). But then, if $N$ is normal in $G$, it has index at most $2$.

Comment: The group you constructed is isomorphic to the one I gave in my first comment. (The Heisenberg group over Z4.) It indeed has order 64. N has order 16, but it is not normal in G: $X\in N$ but $X^Y=iX\notin N$. (And then of course talking about the quotient group doesn't even make sense.)

Comment: @verret. Thanks. Cool, could you also write down the Heisenberg group form then? where are the 64 group elements? I think $i$ and $-1$ are not generated by $X$ and $Y$ because you cannot write them in terms of $X^aY^b$.

Comment: That's not what generated means. $i$ is in the group generated by $X$ and $Y$ because it can be written as a word in $X$ and $Y$. (And, in general, their inverses, but in a finite group, this condition can be dropped.) Here, we have $i=XYX^{-1}Y^{-1}$.

Comment: In any case, even using your terminology and notation, I hope you can agree that the $N_{16}$ you give is not normal in $G$?

Comment: There are 64 elements in $G$ and 16 elements in $N$. You see 64/16=4. I am not 100% sure what is the problem $N$ cannot be the normal subgroup.

Comment: A subgroup is normal in a group if it is closed under conjugation by elements of the group. 
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_subgroup

Comment: Thanks. So I may be wrong, let me modify my answer if I have a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

If $G$ is a group generated by $X$ and $Y$, and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ generated by $X$ and $Y^2$, then $G/N$ has order at most $2$.

So already this is a contradiction, without even using $i$, $-1$  and so on...

Comment: Thanks, that is why I said, I guess $G_{64}$ may be fully generated by $i,X$ and $Y$. Here $i^4=1$.  And $N_{16}$ may be fully generated $-1$, $X$ and $Y^2$.

Comment: When I said the group is "generated" by $X$ and $Y$, but not "fully generated", I mean that the group contains the generators, but the group may contain other generators not mentioned.

Comment: But your answer was wrong, I hope you modify it to be correct.

Comment: I gave a correct answer to your original question. You then edited your question and called my answer wrong... You are also using standard terminology "wrong". I think I'm done here, sorry...

Comment: My advice: you should probably first figure out what it is you really want to ask, and formulate it properly...

Comment: There must be a better way out than this. This does not count as an answer.

Comment: miss-tery ...do not transform your question after you've received (an) answer(s). If you have a different question, submit a different question.

Comment: Please, everyone: Leave your egos behind when you login to MSE. Read my question carefully before you judge it. It is a question from a mathematics professor, not from me. It makes sense. Just do not modify my question further. I had updated it to the less-confusing form.

Comment: miss-tery Precisely: and that applies to you, too: please leave **your** ego at the door.  I have not, in any respect, judged your question. If you realize that you need to transform or change your question, post the altered/changed question as a new question. Own up to the fact that you posted the question posted above; you received an answer to this question. Don't blame the answerer for your lack of clarity.

Comment: I voted up the answer for encouragement, but I wish to see the real answer. Not this superficial one. The question is asked from a discussion with a senior professor. I just try to decode what he really suggested. The question is based on the incomplete info to determine the full answer. The ego sit on you, where you judge people by my and your reputation. But in reality, look again, the posted answer is even more imprecise than my question.

Comment: Happily, someone provides the answer which satisfies my claim. As I said, the question makes sense.